# Disaster Recovery plan with single region deployment

Tags: azure, failover, disaster-recovery, service-level-agreement

One of our customer opt out of multi region deployment of their application due to various reason (assumed calculated SLA for single region is enough for their business need)
However they asked if there is DRP (Disaster Recovery Plan) available for their application.

Maybe there could be some missing pieces in my understand on DRP but I just wonder if DRP is still required (or even possible) for the workload that is not provisioned with multi region redundancy.

Please advise and thank in advance

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/solutions/backup-and-disaster-recovery/

Comment: Its hard to answer since you did not provide details, on other services you use. So lets say you deploy app to multiregion but you have db and its in single region and so on. Have a look at link above i hope it will help